# What adSize for native express adview?

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

How can i set the adSize so that it matches the parent in width on all devices?

I tried `setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);` but for some reason my ads don't show when i use this.

So for now i used `mAdView.setAdSize(new AdSize(320,50);` but not on all devices the width matches the full screen.

**My code**

```
        LinearLayout adContainer  = findViewById(R.id.adContainer);
        mAdView = new NativeExpressAdView(getApplicationContext());
        mAdView.setAdSize(new AdSize(320,50);
        mAdView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
        adContainer.addView(mAdView);

        LinearLayout adContainer2  = findViewById(R.id.adContainer2);
        mAdView2 = new NativeExpressAdView(getApplicationContext());
        mAdView2.setAdSize(new AdSize(320,50);
        mAdView2.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
        adContainer2.addView(mAdView2);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("4EF772AE9549741BE0E1FCA236C7382C").build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        mAdView2.loadAd(adRequest);
```

EDIT

I tried `mAdView.setAdSize(new AdSize(AdSize.FULL_WIDTH, AdSize.AUTO_HEIGHT));`

and it shows an ad with size 320*100, but there are black areas on the left and right side, so how can i set the adsize so that it matches the full screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi unfortunately we don't have that kind of customisation available for DFP ads.
They come in fixed size only i.e. 320x50, 320x100, 320x250 you can't add padding to them can't stretch them. If you do they'll not appear.

Comment: And is there any way to get rid of the black areas on the left and right sides?

Comment: If you're using smart banners it tries to match width of device but image in ads can be small so it ends up showing ad with image and black space on corners that's why i prefer fixed sizes Ads